# creating copies of docker on multiple ports

Tags: python, docker, celery, docker-compose, airflow

what i am trying to do - run airflow in docker with celery
my issue - my celery workers are in containers and i dont know how to scale them

my docker-comopose file:

```
version: '2'  
services:  
mysql:  
  image: mysql:latest  
  restart: always  
  ports:  
      - "3306:3306"  
  environment:  
      - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=true  
      - MYSQL_USER=airflow  
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=airflow  
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=airflow  
  volumes:  
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql  

rabbitmq:  
  image: rabbitmq:3-management  
  restart: always  
  ports:  
      - "15672:15672"  
      - "5672:5672"  
      - "15671:15671"  
  environment:  
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=airflow  
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=airflow 
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST=airflow  
  volumes:  
      - rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq  

webserver:  
  image: airflow:ver5  
  restart: always  
  volumes:  
       - ~/airflow/dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags  
       - /opt/scripts:/opt/scripts      
  environment:  
      - AIRFLOW_HOME=/usr/local/airflow  
  ports:  
      - "8080:8080"  
  links:  
      - mysql:mysql  
      - rabbitmq:rabbitmq  
      - worker:worker  
      - scheduler:scheduler  
  depends_on:  
      - mysql  
      - rabbitmq  
      - worker  
      - schedulerv
  command: webserver  
  env_file: ./airflow.env  

scheduler:
  image: airflow:ver5
  restart: always
  volumes:
       - ~/airflow/dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
       - /opt/scripts:/opt/scripts
  environment:
      - AIRFLOW_HOME=/usr/local/airflow
  links:
      - mysql:mysql
      - rabbitmq:rabbitmq
  depends_on:
      - mysql
      - rabbitmq
  command: scheduler
  env_file: ./airflow.env

worker:
  image: airflow:ver5
  restart: always
  volumes:
       - ~/airflow/dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
       - /opt/scripts:/opt/scripts
  environment:
      - AIRFLOW_HOME=/usr/local/airflow
  ports:
      - "8793:8793"
  links:
      - mysql:mysql
      - rabbitmq:rabbitmq
  depends_on:
      - mysql
      - rabbitmq
  command: worker
  env_file: ./airflow.env
```

So i run the docker-compose command using the above file and it starts an instance of worker on port 8793 on localhost as i am mapping from docker port to localhost. Now what i want to do is scale the number of workers i have and to do that i use the following command:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml scale worker=5
```

but that gives out an error as an instance of worker is already running on 8793. Is there a way to dynamically allocate port to new instances of worker containers as i scale up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could allow your worker nodes to expose the worker port to the host machine on a random port number:

```
worker:
  image: airflow:ver5
  restart: always
  volumes:
       - ~/airflow/dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
       - /opt/scripts:/opt/scripts
  environment:
      - AIRFLOW_HOME=/usr/local/airflow
  ports:
      - "8793"
  links:
      - mysql:mysql
      - rabbitmq:rabbitmq
  depends_on:
      - mysql
      - rabbitmq
  command: worker
  env_file: ./airflow.env
```

Setting `port:` to `- 80` will expose port 80, in the container, to a random port on the host.

Because Docker Compose uses networks, you can actually omit this publish step altogether, and it would work. So simply remove `ports:` from the worker